# DirectX11 Shader Compilation Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shader, hlsl, directx-11

I'm working on a simple DirectX application to display couple of triangles together as Tetrahedron,which Keeps crashing at start.I checked with VS2012 Debugger the error occurs at the stage where Shader is supposed to be compiled from a .fx file,So I assume it's got something to do with the shader.I have no idea what I did wrong.Below is the code of the Shader I'm Using.Assistance required.

```
 struct Light
 {
   float3 pos;
   float4 ambient;
   float4 diffuse;
 };

cbuffer cbPerFrame
 {
  Light light;
 };

cbuffer cbPerObject
{

   float4x4 WVP;
   float4x4 World;
};

  struct VS_OUTPUT
 {
  float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
  float4 worldPos : POSITION;
  float4 color    : COLOR;
  float3 normal : NORMAL;
 };

 VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 inPos : POSITION, float4 inColor : COLOR, float3 normal : NORMAL)
 {
   VS_OUTPUT output;

    output.Pos = mul(inPos, WVP);
output.worldPos = mul(inPos, World);

output.normal = mul(normal, World);

    output.color = inColor;

   return output;
  }    

   float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
  {

    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 diffuse = input.color;

float3 finalColor = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

//Create the vector between light position and pixels position
float3 lightToPixelVec = light.pos - input.worldPos;


//Add the ambient light
float3 finalAmbient = diffuse * light.ambient;

//Turn lightToPixelVec into a unit length vector describing
//the pixels direction from the lights position
lightToPixelVec /= d; 

//Calculate how much light the pixel gets by the angle
//in which the light strikes the pixels surface
float howMuchLight = dot(lightToPixelVec, input.normal);

//If light is striking the front side of the pixel
if( howMuchLight > 0.0f )
{   
    //Add light to the finalColor of the pixel
    finalColor += diffuse * light.diffuse;
}

//make sure the values are between 1 and 0, and add the ambient
finalColor = saturate(finalColor + finalAmbient);   

//Return Final Color
return float4(finalColor, diffuse.a);
  }
```

Here's the part where the Compilation is  supposed to happen

```
   bool InitScene()
   {
 //Compile Shaders from shader file
hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0,
     &VS_Buffer, 0, 0);

if(FAILED(hr))
    {
   MessageBox(0, L"Shader Compilation - Failed",
        L"Error", MB_OK);

   return false;
    }

hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, 
     &PS_Buffer, 0, 0);

//Create the Shader Objects
hr = d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), 
    VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);

hr = d3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), 
    PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

//Set Vertex and Pixel Shaders
d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
d3d11DevCon->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);

light.pos = XMFLOAT3(0.25f, 0.5f, -1.0f);
light.ambient = XMFLOAT4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
light.diffuse = XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

//X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A,NX,NY,NZ
//Create the vertex buffer
Vertex v[] =
{

    Vertex( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    Vertex( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    Vertex( 0.5f,  -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    Vertex( 0.0f,  -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
};

DWORD indices[] = {
    //Front
    0,  1,  2,

    //Left
    0,  1,  3,

    //Right

    0,  2,  3,

    //Bottom

    1,  2,  3

};

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory( &indexBufferDesc, sizeof(indexBufferDesc) );

indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * 4 * 3;
indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;

 iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &iinitData, &IndexBuffer);

//d3d11DevCon->IASetIndexBuffer( squareIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);


D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory( &vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc) );

vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof( Vertex ) * 4;
vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData; 

ZeroMemory( &vertexBufferData, sizeof(vertexBufferData) );
vertexBufferData.pSysMem = v;
hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer( &vertexBufferDesc, &vertexBufferData, &VertBuffer);

//Set the vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof( Vertex );
UINT offset = 0;
//d3d11DevCon->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &squareVertBuffer, &stride, &offset );

//Create the Input Layout
hr = d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout( layout,  
             numElements,VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), 
             VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout );

//Set the Input Layout
d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout( vertLayout );

//Set Primitive Topology
d3d11DevCon->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );

//Create the Viewport
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
viewport.Width = width;
viewport.Height = height;
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 2.0f;

//Set the Viewport
d3d11DevCon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

//Create the buffer to send to the cbuffer in effect file
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbbd; 
ZeroMemory(&cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerObject);
cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;

hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&cbbd, NULL, &cbPerObjectBuffer);

ZeroMemory(&cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerFrame);
cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;

hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&cbbd, NULL, &cbPerFrameBuffer);

//Camera information
camPosition = XMVectorSet( -5.0f, 5.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f );
camTarget = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
camUp = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

//Set the View matrix
camView = XMMatrixLookAtLH( camPosition, camTarget, camUp );

//Set the Projection matrix
camProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( 0.4f*3.14f, width/height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);

return true;

    }
```

Comment: Use the `ppErrorMsgs` argument, then read the buffer as a `char*`.  This will return any compile errors.  Alternatively, you can run `fxc.exe` directly to see if the shader compiles.

Comment: @MooseBoys it gets past the compilation part but it fails at CreateVertexShader and CreatePixelShader part. code at which it is stuck:

             
     d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(),
                                    VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(),
                                    NULL, &VS);
      
     
    d3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(),
                         PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

Comment: CreateShader shouldn't crash, but it may return a failed HRESULT.  If you're sure that's not happening, the only alternatives are that you're not running on supported hardware (in this case, you need `FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0` or higher to run a `_4_0` shader), or it's a driver bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your Vertex shader compiles, but your Pixel Shader doesn't:

```
lightToPixelVec /= d;
```

d is undefined

Since in your code you only check for VS compilation result, that makes sense that it crashes when trying to create Pixel Shader (as you send an invalid pointer).

As mentionned in comment, it's also important to check feature level, in case you develop for desktop/laptop pretty much any device should be at least feature level 10.1

In case of phone your should use one of those profile (whichever matches best):
ps_4_0_level_9_1, ps_4_0_level_9_2, ps_4_0_level_9_3