# Shaders and Directx11 compilation in c++

Tags: c++, compilation, directx, shader, directx-11

I am trying to create a Directx 11 program using c++ . The code used to work before I added ***Normal*** to the code .Now it doesnt compile the shader at all .It keeps giving me access Violation *0X0000* Error.

I tried using d3dErrorBlolb but wasnt very helpful.The problem seems to lie in this part of the code.

```
void InitPipeline(HWND hwnd)
{

ID3D10Blob * BVS = 0,*BPS  = 0;
ID3D10Blob * BErrorVS,*BErrorPs;

HRESULT hr1 = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Test.fx",0,0,"VS","vs_4_0",0,0,0,&BVS,&BErrorVS,0);
HRESULT hr =  D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Test.fx",0,0,"PS","ps_4_0",0,0,0,&BPS,&BErrorPs,0);


if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Error %08X   %5s\n",hr,(char*)BErrorVS);
    MessageBox(hwnd,L"Pixel shader not created ",L"",0);

}
if(FAILED(hr1))
{   MessageBox(hwnd,L"Vertex shader not created ",L"",0);}
dev->CreateVertexShader(BVS->GetBufferPointer(),BVS->GetBufferSize(),0,&BoxVShader);
dev->CreatePixelShader(BPS->GetBufferPointer(),BPS->GetBufferSize(),0,&BoxPixelShader);


   // create the input layout object
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
{
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"NORMAL",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,12,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
  //  {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}

};
//SecureZeroMemory(&Bin);
dev->CreateInputLayout(ied,2,BVS->GetBufferPointer(),BVS->GetBufferSize(),&BInputLayout);

devcon->VSSetShader(BoxVShader,0,0);
devcon->PSSetShader(BoxPixelShader,0,0);
devcon->IASetInputLayout(BInputLayout);
```

}

The **Test.fx** file

```
  ecbuffer ConstantBuffer:register(b0)
{
 matrix world;
 matrix view;
 matrix project;
 float3[2] LightDir;
 float4[2] LightColor;

}

struct Vout{
float4 pos:SV_POSITION;
float4 normal : NORMAL;
};


Vout VS(float3 pos:POSITION,float3 Norm:NORMAL)
{
  Vout vo = (Vout)0;
  vo.pos = mul(float4(pos,1),world);
  vo.pos = mul(vo.pos,view);
  vo.pos = mul(vo.pos,project);

  vo.normal = mul(float4(Norm,1),world);


  return vo;



}


float4 PS(float4 pos:SV_POSITION,float4 normal:NORMAL):SV_TARGET
{
    float4 col;

    for(int i=0; i < 2;++i)
    {
        col += saturate(dot(normal,LightDir[i])) * LightColor[i] ;
    }
    return col;
 }
```

Can anyone **please** be kind enough to help me out...

If possible **please** do explain why this keeps happening **always**..What am I doing wrong here

Please do help me.I desperately need to solve this problem....

Thank you...

Comment: I cannot be of much help, but I found this stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546018/directx11-shader-compilation-issue then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx finally http://www.sunandblackcat.com/tipFullView.php?l=eng&topicid=26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While compiling HLSL at runtime is nice for learning and iteration, it's actually a lot easier to debug the HLSL by compiling it with the command-line:

`fxc test.fx /Tvs_4_0 /EVS` and `fxc test.fx /Tps_4_0 /EPS`

The second fails because you failed to set the initial value for col in the Pixel Shader:

> test.fx(40,25-47): warning X3206: 'dot': implicit truncation of vector type
>
> test.fx(40,9-64): error X4000: variable 'col' used without having  been completely initialized
>
> compilation failed; no code produced

The fix is trivial:

```
float4 PS(float4 pos:SV_POSITION,float4 normal:NORMAL):SV_TARGET
{
    float4 col = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < 2;++i)
    {
        col += saturate(dot(normal,LightDir[i])) * LightColor[i] ;
    }
    return col;
 }
```

You are getting an AV because you have the wrong handling of the failed compiler output, you forgot to initialize both `BErrorVS` and `BErrorPS` to null, and you are trying to output `BErrorVS` when the VS succeeded, but the PS failed. It should be:

```
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Error %08X   %5s\n",hr,(char*)BErrorPS->GetBufferPointer());
    MessageBox(hwnd,L"Pixel shader not created ",L"",0);

}
```

Also you should remember that `BErrorVS` and `BErrorPS` can be set to a non-null value even if `SUCCEEDED(hr))` since it can be reporting only non-fatal warnings.

See [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ...Can you please tell me where that command line goes so that i can use it to debug it...Thanks again

Comment: If you have VS 2012, look for "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012". With VS 2013, look for the "Visual Studio Tools" folder which has the "Developer Command Prompt" entries. If you are using the legacy DirectX SDK, look for "DirectX SDK Command Prompt".

Comment: You can also add it as a custom build step in MSBuild (the build system for VS), or as a custom build rule for the .fx file. Both of these allow you to enter arbitrary command line instructions with access to the VS environment variable set.

Comment: With VS 2012 and 2013, there's a built-in handler for .fx/.hlsl files that uses FXC. The main problem is that MSBuild assumes single-source file -> single-result file which only works for legacy ``fx_`` profiles. For other uses you typically compile the same file many times with different parameters. The only way to emulate that with MSBuild is to have a file for each target and make heavy use of #include. In the end, except for trivial cases, it's usually a lot easier to use the command-line with a batch file--see [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) for example.

Comment: Hi thanks guys for all the help.But I cant seem to compile a file from DirecxSDK commandprompt. I set the directory usinf cd  (Path)                     Then When i use fxc Test.hlsl/Tvs_4_0/EVS   it shows an error in red saying that it easrches from start of program  Do you have any idea why this happens                             Thanks

Comment: You need all the spaces: ``fxc Test.hlsl /Tvs_4_0 /EVS``